# Azure Service bus Queue connection issue

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus

I am currently facing strange issue while working with Azure ServiceBus Queue.

If I insert into queue only single record then it works fine.Record insert into queue successfully.

But when I try to insert more record simultaneously (say using Jmeter for test),after some time I am getting following error.

> Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusCommunicationException: A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond

It works fine for individual insert into queue.I have tried increasing timeout period in connection string but could not work

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44757532/a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-not-properly-respond

Comment: `servicebus` as it relates to `EventHub` resource?

Comment: @ershoaib no duplicate.This one is different and related to Service Bus.

Comment: @BrettCaswell No ServiceBus is not related with EventHub. I am directly inserting my record from my C# application to queue.

Comment: @sandip, Did you resolve this issue? If yes, what is the fix for this issue?